# GNU Make: How to add an option in front of every entry of a list

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a problem where I want to create a variable that looks like this,

```
INCDIRS = -I dir0 -I dir1 -Idir2 -I dir3 ... -I dirN
```

where **dir1, ... , dirN** are the names of all the subdirectories some base directory, **base_dir**.

How would I go about building up this variable?  Originally, I thought I could do the following,

```
INCDIRS = $(shell for x in `find base_dir -type -d -print`; do echo -I $x; done;)
```

but this just results in

```
INCDIRS = -I -I -I -I ... -I
```

If anyone could explain how to do this, or explain why my original command got the output that it did, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: *Always* run make with `--warn`. You would then have been told `Makefile:n: warning: undefined variable 'x'`. Then you would have realised that `$x` is expanded (to nothing) by make, _before_ passing an incorrect command line to the shell. (You should have said `... do echo -I $$x ...`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your `INCDIRS` assignment. One is in the `find` command. It should be `find -type d -print` (or just `find -type d`; the `-print` is superfluous here). The other error the use of `$x`. You need to escape the `$` with another `$`:

```
INCDIRS = $(shell for x in `find base_dir -type d -print`; do echo -I $$x; done;)
```

Comment: Hi Martega, if that fixes your problem I think David deserves you mark his answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could first get the list of directories, then add -I in front of each one:

```
SOURCE_DIRS := $(shell find base_dir -type d -print)
INCDIRS      = $(addprefix -I,$(SOURCE_DIRS))
```

which may be better if you need $(SOURCE_DIRS) for something else.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for all along!